# How to send JSON via socket.io

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have this on the server:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (client) {
    client.on('message', function (message) {
        try {
            var incomingJSON = JSON.parse(message);
            console.log("Message received");
            console.log(incomingJSON.message);
            console.log(incomingJSON.coordinates);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            client.disconnect();
        }
    });
});
```

And this on the client:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8008');
$("#ready").click(function(){
    socket.emit("message", {message: "ready", coordinates: "21"});
});
```

And I got this on node.js console instead of my message:

```
[SyntaxError: Unexpected token o]
info: booting client
info: transport end by forced client disconnection
debug: websocket writing 0::
info: transport end (booted)
```

Please help me to send my JSON from client to server and tell me what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You doesn't need to parse JSON in `on` event.
Just use message variable as object.

For example:

```
 console.log(message.message);
```

Comment: Good luck with nodejs ;)